# Streaming blob using Spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I need to write a ETL where I need to migrate blob(s) from one storage to another. Size of the individual blob can be as big as 100gb.

- Is it possible to stream those blob using Spring batch framework? I see there is a concept of reader, processor and writer. What I'm not sure is, if it's possible to get a handle of my blob source InputStream in the Spring batch writer, so that I can stream data from my source to sink datasource.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this simply a matter of move BLOB X from one datastore to another or is this a matter of doing something else with these BLOBS?

Comment: Moving them around and while moving, I need to do lot of things like virus scanning, encryption etc. But those things are figured out, only concern is how to get those BLOB moved across faster and in reliable manner.

Answer (score 0):

I think ItemReader/Processor/Writer will not help you here. This abstraction is good for transforming records within database. But in your case it's complicated because record will not fit into the memory.

What you can get use of Reader/Processor/Writer approach (and spring batch) is transaction handling and restartability.

So main problem here: you need to find proper way how to stream blobs from one storage to another. Then this logic should go to either Processor or Writer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think your approach makes sense, I was also thinking Spring batch is good for small unit of work where a record of table in one db needs to be migrated to another db. Again thanks for you reply. I will probably not use Spring Batch to solve this kind of problem.